External Microphone turns off when MacBook is closed
I know the MacBook internal microphone is disabled when the MacBook is closed. I bought an external webcam with microphone, so I could use that for meetings when I am at my desk setup with a large external display and have the laptop closed. That's been working perfectly until today.
Now, the external microphone works fine when the MacBook is open and it doesn't work when the MacBook is closed. The webcam video works when the MacBook is open and closed.
I can use https://www.onlinemictest.com/ and see the external webcam microphone work with the laptop open and not work when closed.
Last night I installed a new macOS system update, I didn't really pay attention to it, and while I'm not sure that caused the problem, I suspect that's what caused the issue.
Anyone else experiencing this?
Any workarounds?
